# sapper dev/build/export sudden unresolved errors

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

Did some work on a branch, made some changes, and all of a sudden an attempt to `yarn dev` resulted in "Unexpected token/resolve" errors (and then cascading errors after that...):

```
✗ server
Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
1: declare module '@sapper/app'
           ^
2: declare module '@sapper/server'
3: declare module '@sapper/service-worker'
✗ client
Could not resolve '../../../routes/_error.svelte' from src/routes/node_modules/@sapper/internal/App.svelte
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/dev/web/sites/eetheissen/__sapper__/dev/server/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I did a 'git reset --hard HEAD' to just start over since the head build fine.  Same error.

Then I checked out the master branch, which I know built fine, previously.  `yarn dev` results in the same error.

Finally, I moved the repo aside and re-cloned the master from github.  It builds (whew!!), and I'm able to continue.

It's a bit of a mystery - I don't know why this should have happen on the working branch or, especially, the master branch that built ok before, and I don't quite undersand the error or how to track it down.  The error seems deep inside sapper and my guess is it's a typescript error.  I'm not using typescript, and, as far as I know, didn't do anything to trigger typescript.  But, I presume sapper itself uses typescript, and now it's throwing typescript errors.

At this point, I'm able to move on and am really just reporting experience.  If someone knows off the top of your head why this should happen, I'd really like to know so I can avoid or at least know how to handle it in the future.

Comment: I don't know why it happens but you can try to delete the __sapper__ folder instead of re-cloning the repo, all the built files are here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try if it happens, again.